# Unable to start S3 TransferUtility

Tags: android, amazon-s3

when I am trying to start the TransferUtility for the uploading object to S3 bucket,i am getting the following error:

```
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.ntt.vault/com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

the code used is :

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = mTransferUtility.upload(Constants.NTT_AWS_S3_BUCKET, key, file);
        transferObserver.setTransferListener (new UploadListener());
```

I made sure that "key" is proper and "filename" is also proper one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this issue can be fixed by adding the service in the android manifest file.

```
 <service android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to add network state permission (in the manifest) for the S3 service to work properly:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from

```
<service android:name= "com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService" android:enabled="true" />
```

We also need to give below permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```